# Java newbie: Can't find a syntax error

Tags: java

I've recently started to learn Java and need to find a syntax error in a piece of code below. Would also really appreciate if someone could explain why it's wrong.

```
public boolean isDivisible(int a, int b) {
    return a % b != 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know there's a syntax error?

Comment: There is no syntax error in this code.

Comment: Please share the errormessage

Comment: There is no syntax error, but a semantical.

Comment: My magic ball is saying that you are doing something wrong. Please fix it.

Comment: Gotta get me one of those magic balls :-)

Comment: Use @paxdiablo implementation, to avoid zero-divided problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *syntax* error in that code, as you can see by incorporating it into a complete program and seeing that it compiles okay:

```
public class Test{
    public boolean isDivisible(int a, int b) {
        return a % b != 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.isDivisible(10, 2));
        System.out.println(t.isDivisible(10, 3));
    }
}
```

However, there *is* a logic problem by virtue of the fact it outputs `false` followed by `true`, despite the fact that ten *is* divisible by two but *isn't* divisible by three.

In other words, you have the sense of the comparison the wrong way around. A number can be considered divisible is the modulo operator gives you a zero value (not a non-zero value, as you currently have it).

A better implementation, correcting the logic error and covering the case of trying to divide by zero as well, would be something like:

```
public boolean isDivisible(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return false;
    return (a % b) == 0;
}
```